# onbeforeunload Not firing until work is done

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Here is my code:

```
            window.onbeforeunload = function()
            {
                return 'some warning message';
            }

            window.onload = function () {
                importIndicator(0);
            }
```

What I do is to get data from the server and draw a chart. After that I upload the chart's SVG data back to the server to make a picture. The problem is that while this transaction is running I need to tell the user not to leave the page.

But the `onbeforeunload` is not firing until after all the work on the page is completed and by then it is too late.

Why is that and what can I do about it?

**Update:** upon further inspection it seems to work unless I try to close the popup by doing <kbd>ctr</kbd> + <kbd>w</kbd>. But it still requires waiting a second or two before it start working.

Comment: Showing custom message removed due security reasons, instead of that browsers show their own message.

Comment: @DavorMlinaric I am aware of that, I just want to prevent the user from closing the popop by accident.

Comment: user can anyway close browser, you can't (should not) prevent user to close window. just put some message while loading data. or, what you can do to try to capture when mouse leave (mouseleave, mouseout) window and then to show alert.